# Storing integers from file to 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to import similar to this

```
5 5
1 1
3 3
1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

files into 2D array but I am having hard time, this is my code so far, which does nothing, there aren't syntactic mistakes, so I don't get any errors but a blank console and I don't know what I did wrong. The size of the array is the first 2 numbers inside the file.

```
package main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class oboroten {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x, y;
    x = y = 0;
    int[][] maze = new int[x][y];
    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\mazes\\input.txt"));
        x = reader.nextInt();
        y = reader.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++){
                maze[i][j] = reader.nextInt();
                System.out.println(maze[i][j]);
            }
        }       
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        System.out.println("Problem with the file");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Comment: `int[][] maze = new int[x][y];` you set the size of your array to 0.  wonder why you don't get outofbounds error

Comment: Because `for(... i<x)`. Nothing ever happens, because `0<0` is never true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initial you array with the size 0. So nothing will be addet there.

You have to initial the array **after** you read the file and get the dimensions.
Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x, y;
    int[][] maze;
    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\mazes\\input.txt"));
        x=reader.nextInt();
        y=reader.nextInt();
        maze = new int[x][y];
        for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<y; j++){
                maze[i][j]=reader.nextInt();
                System.out.println(maze[i][j]);
            }
        }       
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        System.out.println("Problem with the file");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: x and y will remain 0 if reader.nextInt() returns 0; i.e if the file starts with 0 0

Comment: Why should the file start with `0 0`? @Eritrean

Comment: @Gendarme Why not?

Comment: There is nothing that suggests that the file starts with `0 0`. The `5 5` at the beginning probably intentional to produce a 5x5 matrix. However, the `1 1` and `3 3` is ruining everything, so there's some confusion here.

Comment: @Eritrean if the file starts with 0 0 an empty array will be produced, as expected.

Comment: the `1 1` and `3 3` are start and end point for the matrix and they should be ignored by the array, i forgot to say that sorry

Comment: I'm glad I could help you @Tom. You may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.